# Can you assign scripts to page elements (shapes etc.)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I want to make an interactive slideshow for students.

I want to add shapes, so when you click on the shape it will run an Apps Script script. This is possible in Google Sheets.

So, I thought that you could do it with slides as well.

Comment: Not possible. What would the script do when clicked? You can add URLs which could call a webapp depending on your end goal.

Comment: I want to have pictures and diagrams on the slide and a multiple choice question.  Then a box next to the answers.  When the student clicks a box. It would add and subtract to keep a score and then advance the next slide.  I could keep the scores in an external spreadsheet.

Comment: Sounds like something I'd do with a webapp contained in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Definitely not worth the investment of time I'd imagine. I'd stick to Forms or Quizzes for making slides more interactive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to run a [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) by clicking a shape in Google Slides like you can in [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). But, you can accomplish a similar effect by adding a shape with a link to a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that runs your script when opened. For Example, here is a script for a web app that changes the text on the first shape of the first slide whenever someone visits it.

```
function doGet() {
   const presentation = SlidesApp.openById(id); // presentation id
   const slide = presentation.getSlideById(id); // slide id
   const textBox = slide.getShapes().filter(_s => _s.getObjectId() === objectId)[0].getText(); // id of your text box object
   const clicks = Number(textBox.asString());
   textBox.setText(clicks + 1);
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thanks for clicking!"); //message to display when user visits your webapp
}
```

Here is a working example:
[Google Slide Presentation with Clickable Button](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1iDnyoil0o-zyRLyjYeHfJmEcH6aFZtHntPMCcPPZZSA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

At this time it's not possible on Google Slides.

The guide about [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) only mention that scripts could be assigned to shapes on Google Sheets. It doesn't mention that this is possible in Google Slides.

Other documents says that the [Slides service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/) "allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Slides files", by the other hand the [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview) "lets you create and modify Google Slides presentations".