# Is there a way to link a script in Google Slides to an object?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I currently have a script with a dropdown menu to roll a dice in Google Slides but I would like to link the script to an image of dice in the slide itself. Is this possible to do so I can click the dice and the script will run?

Here is my script so far:

```
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('dice')
  .addItem('2 Dice', 'roll2')
  
  .addToUi();
}



function getRndInteger(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
  
}




function roll2(){
  var math = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math);
  var math2 = getRndInteger(1,6);
  Logger.log(math2);
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
 ui.alert('You rolled a '+math+' and a '+math2);
  
}
```

Comment: If you mean something like [clickable images](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) in Sheets, I don't think so. I might be mistaken, though - if a Slides expert comes by, they might be able to answer definitively. Also, I removed [hyperlink] tag as you are assigning a script, not a URI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you assign apps scripts to elements (shapes etc.) on Google Slides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47033186/can-you-assign-apps-scripts-to-elements-shapes-etc-on-google-slides)